# Equal (=) Vs left arrow (<-) symbols in haskell

Tags: haskell

Working code:

```
import System
main = do
     [file1, file2] <- getArgs
     --copy file contents
     str <- readFile file1
     writeFile file2 str
```

Crashing code:

```
import System
main = do
       [file1, file2] = getArgs
       str = readFile file1
       writeFile file2 str
```

When I tried, it threw an error as:

> a.hs:6:18: parse error on input '='

So, how different is `<-` from `=`?

Comment: You need to understand Monad de-sugaring to get an actual idea of how this fits.

Comment: @Sibi that's technically true but I feel it should be possible to answer this question without mentioning the M-word. After all, m***ds are just one way of dealing with IO in a pure language. Haskell would still have a separation between pure and impure code even if it didn't have m****ds built into the language, and this problem (or one like it) would still exist.

Comment: @ChrisTaylor While it's possible to answer this question without explaining Monad, I really doubt if it will help the OP in grasping the concept. That being said, there are lot of good answers down here.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

To understand the real difference, you have to understand monads, and the desugaring described by (the now deleted user) user1804599 in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28624445/3234959).

For the specific case of the IO monad, as in your `getArgs` example, a rough but useful intuition can be made as follows:

- `x <- action` *runs* the IO `action`, gets its result, and binds it to `x`
- `let x = action` defines `x` to be equivalent to `action`, but does not run anything. Later on, you can use `y <- x` meaning `y <- action`.

Programmers coming from imperative languages which allow closures, may draw this rough parallel comparison with JavaScript:

```javascript
var action = function() { print(3); return 5; }

// roughly equivalent to x <- action
print('test 1')
var x = action()  // output:3
// x is 5

// roughly equivalent to let y = action
print('test 2')
var y = action    // output: nothing
// y is a function

// roughly equivalent to z <- y
print('test 3')
var z = y()       // output:3
// z is 5
```

Again: this comparison focuses on IO, only. For other monads, you need to check what `>>=` actually is, and think about the desugaring of `do`.

Answer (score 66):

```
do
    x <- y
    f x
```

is equivalent to:

```
y >>= \x -> f x
```

---

```
do
    let x = y
    f x
```

is equivalent to

```
f y
```

i.e. `let`/`=` does no monadic bind whereas `<-` does.

Comment: Saying `let x = y in f x` (which really *is* equivalent to the 2nd do expression) is "equivalent" to `f y` is dangerous, mainly because it may not be obvious to the reader what "equivalent" means; the values of these two expressions are the same, but their semantics may be different.

Comment: @user2407038 no, they are exactly the same thing. There isn't a single difference.

Comment: this give me a hard time (simplified version) `testF box = do a <- box; let b = do x <- Just "from let"; return x; return (fmap (++ box) b)` the let smuggle a monad without any additional return, b is put `silently` in the box. In the same time I tried with `... b <- do x <- Just "from let"; return x ..."` here it compiles but I didn't find what to give to testF to run it:-)

Answer (score 24):

The code doesn't compile because the types don't match. Let's load up a GHCI session and look at the types of the functions you're using -

```
> :t writeFile
writeFile :: FilePath -> String -> IO ()
>
> :t readFile
readFile :: FilePath -> IO String
```

So `writeFile` wants a `FilePath` and a `String`. You want to get the `String` from `readFile` - but `readFile` returns `IO String` instead of `String`.

Haskell is a very principled language. It has a distinction between *pure* functions (which give the same outputs every time they are called with the same arguments) and *impure* code (which may give different results, e.g. if the function depends on some user input). Functions that deal with input/output (IO) always have a return type which is marked with `IO`. The type system ensures that you cannot use impure `IO` code inside pure functions - for example, instead of returning a `String` the function `readFile` returns an `IO String`.

This is where the `<-` notation is important. It allows you to get at the `String` inside the `IO` and it ensures that whatever you do with that string, the function you are defining will always be marked with `IO`. Compare the following -

```
> let x = readFile "tmp.txt"
> :t x
x :: IO String
```

which isn't what we want, to this

```
> y <- readFile "tmp.txt"
> :t y
y :: String
```

which is what we want. If you ever have a function that returns an `IO a` and you want to access the `a` , you need to use `<-` to assign the result to a name. If your function doesn't return `IO a` , or if you don't want to get at the `a` inside the `IO` then you can just use `=`.

Comment: The OP's code has a *syntax error*. It seems that should probably be addressed before the type error that hides behind it.

Comment: it could be stressed that having to go through the `<-` to get to the computed result *forces* one to do this *inside* the IO `do` block, to be able to do this. thus enforcing the separation of impure IO from pure code.

Answer (score 21):

```
let x = readFile file1
```

This takes the action "`readFile file1`" and stores *the action* in `x`.

```
x <- readFile file1
```

This *executes* the action "`readFile file1`" and stores *the result* of the action in `x`.

In the first example, `x` is an unexecuted I/O action object. In the second example, `x` is the contents of a file on disk.