# Why you can't use substitution inside a do block while you can use let (binding)?

Tags: haskell

Why can't you use substitution inside a do block?
This code works fine.

```
test :: (x -> x) -> [x] -> [x]
test f a = map f a
main :: IO ()
main = do
  let sq x = x * x :: Int
  let ret = test sq [1,2,3]
  print ret
```

But if you remove the let's inside the do block, I got compile errors.

```
parse error on input ‘=’
Perhaps you need a 'let' in a 'do' block?
e.g. 'let x = 5' instead of 'x = 5'
```

Is "let x = y" equivalent to "x <- y" inside a do block?
So if the right hand side returns a IO something, you need to use let's (or <-) ?
I know it's a dummy question but I always get compile error with this.
eii

Comment: [About `let =` vs `<-`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28624408/equal-vs-left-arrow-symbols-in-haskell/28625714#28625714)

Comment: No, they are not the same. Consider `do` / `let p = putStrLn "hello world"` / `p` / `p` (imagine each / is a line break with appropriate indentation)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`let` is how you assign a value to a name inside a `do` block. `let x = y` is not equivalent to `x <- y`. Inside a `do` block, `let` desugars like this.

```
do let x = y
   ...
```

becomes

```
let x = y
in do ...
```

whereas

```
do x <- y
   ...
```

becomes

```
do y >>= (\x -> ...)
```

---

Bare `=` is only for top-level assignments, for defining functions and constants (which are a lot like 0-argument functions).