# What is the difference between `let .. in do` and `<-` notation in Haskell Monads?

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors, monads, type-mismatch, do-notation

I'm trying to implement a function which converts a string to a list of Maybe Ints, e.g. `readInts "1 2 42 foo" = [Just 1,Just 2,Just 42,Nothing]`.

My first aproach was:

```
readInts (s::String) = do {
    ws <- words s;
    return (map (readMaybe::(String -> Maybe Int)) ws)
}
```

This resulted in the following error:

```
lab_monad.hs:20:52:
    Couldn't match type ‘Char’ with ‘[Char]’
    Expected type: [String]
      Actual type: String
    In the second argument of ‘map’, namely ‘ws’
    In the first argument of ‘return’, namely
      ‘(map (readMaybe :: String -> Maybe Int) ws)’
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

What I tried next (and worked), was:

```
readInts (s::String) = do {
    let ws = (words s) in do
        return (map (readMaybe::(String -> Maybe Int)) ws)
}
```

My question here is, `words s` obviously is of type `[String]`. Why does the interpreter say it is a `String`? What am I not understanding about `<-` operator?

Comment: Why are you trying to use `do` notation here in the first place?

Comment: To learn how to use the `do` notation, even if it is not the best solution here.

Comment: @TomaszGarbus `do`-notation is completely irrelevant to what you're trying to do here. I recommend reading [the relevant LYAH chapter](http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads), since a full explanation of Monads and `do`-notation is too broad for one question.

Comment: It's not completely irrelevant; it's just incorrectly mixing monadic operations and `map`.

Comment: Potentially relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28624408/equal-vs-left-arrow-symbols-in-haskell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ws <- words s`, in the list monad, nondeterministically assigns *one* word from `words s` to `ws`; the remaining code simply works with that one word, and the `return` function "magically" combines the results of working on *all* the words into the result list.

```
readInts s = do
   ws <- words s  -- ws represents *each* word in words s
   return (readMaybe ws)
```

The `do` notation is just syntactic sugar for using monadic `bind`:

```
readInts s = words s >>= (\ws -> return (readMaybe ws))
```

Without using the `Monad` instance for lists, you can use `map` to apply the same function to each word.

```
readInts s = map readMaybe (words s)
```

---

`let`, on the other hand, simply provides a name for a more complicated expression to be used in another expression. It can be considered syntactic sugar for defining and immediately applying an anonymous function. That is,

```
let x = y + z in f x
```

is equivalent to

```
(\x -> f x) (y + z)
  ^     ^      ^
  |     |      |
  |     |      RHS of let binding
  |     part after "in"
  LHS of let binding
```

A `let` statement with multiple bindings is equivalent to nested `let` statements:

```
let x = y + z
    a = b + c
in x + a
```

is equivalent to

```
let x = y + z
in let a = b + c
   in x + a
```

which desugars to

```
(\x -> (\a -> x + a)(b + c))(y + z)
```