# Haskell: Wrong typing when making an IO Map out of IO Strings

Tags: haskell, io, monads, typing

I have a function with the following signature:

```
Config -> IO (Map.Map String String)
```

that is used to extract a FilePath from the Config, then load that file (contains lines of text), and then parse the lines into keys and values - which is why I need to save them into map, preferably.

So, I have created the following function:

```
let lns = liftM lines $ readFile $ getSet $ listF c in
    foldM (\m n -> liftM3 Map.insert n n m) (return Map.empty) lns
```

Now, I would hope that Haskell realizes that I want this to be a IO Map of Strings (for simplicity, I dont parse the lines into keys and vals for now, and just put the whole line in there).

However, I get the following errors:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘Map.Map String’ with ‘IO’
  Expected type: IO (Map.Map String String)
    Actual type: Map.Map
                   String (Map.Map String (Map.Map String String))
• In the expression:
    foldM (\ m n -> liftM3 Map.insert n n m) (return Map.empty) lns
  In the expression:
    let lns = liftM lines $ readFile $ getSet $ listF c
    in foldM (\ m n -> liftM3 Map.insert n n m) (return Map.empty) lns
  In an equation for ‘getEpisodeNames’:
      getEpisodeNames c
        | listF c == NotSet = return Map.empty
        | otherwise
        = let lns = liftM lines $ readFile $ getSet $ listF c
          in foldM (\ m n -> liftM3 Map.insert n n m) (return Map.empty) lns


• Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Map.Map String String’
  Expected type: Map.Map
                   String (Map.Map String (Map.Map String String))
    Actual type: Map.Map String (Map.Map String String)
• In the expression: liftM3 Map.insert n n m
  In the first argument of ‘foldM’, namely
    ‘(\ m n -> liftM3 Map.insert n n m)’
  In the expression:
    foldM (\ m n -> liftM3 Map.insert n n m) (return Map.empty) lns


• Couldn't match type ‘[]’ with ‘Map.Map String’
  Expected type: IO (Map.Map String String)
    Actual type: IO [String]
• In the third argument of ‘foldM’, namely ‘lns’
  In the expression:
    foldM (\ m n -> liftM3 Map.insert n n m) (return Map.empty) lns
  In the expression:
    let lns = liftM lines $ readFile $ getSet $ listF c
    in foldM (\ m n -> liftM3 Map.insert n n m) (return Map.empty) lns
```

From that, it seems that `return Map.empty` tries to wrap the Map in something else than IO monad, which honestly does not make sense to me.

As Haskell never makes mistakes, it is clear to me that I have messed up somewhere, I just can't find, where (though I am pretty sure it is in the second line, as I have checked the lns for the correct type using `:t` in ghci). I also tried rewriting the function to >>= notation instead of let ... in ..., but it didn't help. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think you are using `let` instead of `<-` (in a `do` block). Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28624408/equal-vs-left-arrow-symbols-in-haskell

Comment: I am not using a do block, nor the >>= notation, that snippet i put here is actually the whole definition. Also, using the do notation gives exactly the same error (plus, as i said, the `lns` variable is actually typed correctly, it is the foldM result that is wrong).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature of `foldM` is

```
foldM :: Monad m => (a -> b -> m a) -> a -> [b] -> m a
```

Let's see what you've got:

```
return Map.empty :: IO (Map String String)
lns :: IO [String]
```

That definitely does not match parameters `a` and `[b]`. Fixing the former is easy: just use `Map.empty`. For the latter, you need access to what's inside `lns`, which is what the bind operator is for:

```
>>= :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

Hence

```
lns >>= foldM (…) Map.empty
```

But since you operation is pure, you might as well just use `fmap` and `foldl`

```
foldl (…) Map.empty <$> lns
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I have actually managed to fix the code, though I am still not entirely sure where the problem was, so i would be still grateful if someone could point that out.

So, instead of

```
let lns = liftM lines $ readFile $ getSet $ listF c in
    foldM (\m n -> liftM3 Map.insert n n m) (return Map.empty) lns
```

I used

```
(readFile . getSet $ listF c)
    >>= (\tx -> return $ lines tx)
    >>= (\lns -> return $ foldl (\m n -> Map.insert n n m) Map.empty lns)
```

Comment: I think you don't understand yet the difference between `f (g x)` (which is equivalent to `let y=g x in f y`) and `g x >>= f`. In IO, the latter runs the IO action `g x`, takes its result, and passes it to `f`, running the action returned by `f`. The former does not run `g x`, but it passes the whole action to `f`, which must have type `f :: IO something -> ...`. In imperative languages, it's (very roughly) the difference between `f(() => g(x))` (the former) and `f(g(x))` (the latter) -- the former does not run `g(x)`. Perhaps a monad tutorial could help, here.