# Ambigous type variable that prevents the constraint

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I am fiddling around with IO and i do not understand the following **error** :

```
* Ambiguous type variable `a0' arising from a use of `readLine'
      prevents the constraint `(Console a0)' from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what `a0' should be.
      These potential instance exist:
        instance Console Int -- Defined at Tclass.hs:8:14
    * In the second argument of `(+)', namely `readLine'
      In the second argument of `($)', namely `(2 + readLine)'
      In the expression: putStrLn . show $ (2 + readLine)
   |
17 |     useInt =putStrLn . show $ (2+readLine)
```

**Code**

```
module Tclass where
    import System.Environment

    class Console a where
        writeLine::a->IO()
        readLine::IO a

    instance Console Int where
        writeLine= putStrLn . show 

        readLine = do
            a <- getLine
            let b= (read  a)::Int
            return b

    useInt::IO()
    useInt =putStrLn . show $ (2+readLine)
```

**P.S** i do not understand shouldn't the compiler infer the type of the  instance for `readLine` and make the addition with `2` in the `useInt` method ?

Comment: `putStrLn . show` should always be replaced by `print`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`2` is not only an `Int` in Haskell but it is of any numeric type, including `Float,Double,Integer,...`. Its type is `Num a => a` -- a polymorphic type fitting each numeric type.

So, you could use `(2::Int)` instead. Then you'll discover that `(2::Int) + readLine` is a type error, since `readLine :: Int` is wrong, we only get `readLine :: IO Int`.

You can try this, instead

```
useInt :: IO ()
useInt = do
   i <- readLine
   putStrLn . show (2 + i :: Int)
```

Comment: I do not understand the following: Shouldn't the `readLine` method return an `Int` when used by another method since the only `IO` part was finished with `a<-getLine` ,so after this line shouldn't the returning result be a pure one?So if i have a method `mymethod::IO Char`  that is used by another method `secondMethod` i still need to access the `mymethod` result with `<-` inside the `secondMethod`?

Comment: So a correct compact way it should be:  `useInt::IO()
    useInt =putStrLn . show $ ((2::Int)+(<-readLine))` ? Can you oneline the (<-) operator?

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian `<-` is not an operator itself but syntactic sugar. What you need here is the _monadic chaining combinator_ [`=<<`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:-61--60--60-). `useInt = print . ((2::Int)+) =<< readLine`. (That's indeed also what `do {i<-readLine; print (2+i::Int)}` desugars to.)

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian `readLine` is an `IO Int`, not an `Int`. The former type says "you could have an int, if you let me do I/O", the latter says "you can have an int (without I/O)". The `.. <- ..` syntax in `do` blocks lets you run the IO action and get its result (which is now I/O-free). However, the whole `do` expression will have an IO type (since it did I/O after all!). Note that `do x <- readLine ; f x` runs `getLine` once, while `g readLine` passes the whole IO action `readLine` to `g` which might use it twice e.g. `g act = do x<-act; y<-act; ...`

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian Maybe you should read a monad tutorial to know more about the IO monad, and/or have a look at [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28625714/3234959) which could clarify some aspects.

Comment: But this means that if i have a hierarchy of 3 methods `m0` ,`m1`,`m2` where `m0::IO a` and `m1` uses `m0` , and  `m2` uses `m1` , then i have to always get the value  "out of the monad bind" am i right? `m2=<<m1=<<m0`. I thought that somewhere in the hierarchy you can obtain the pure value and continue with that without "tainting" all your methods.