# What does "<-" mean?

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension, do-notation

In this tutorial http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out the author writes this piece of code.

```
boomBangs xs = [ if x < 10 then "BOOM!" else "BANG!" | x <- xs, odd x]
```

And then later executes it like this

```
boomBangs[7..13]
```

And my question is, what does the "<-" operator do? To me this seems like it would cause recursive behavior, since I am referencing what looks to me like a function inside a function, or perhaps defining how to create a list comprehension.

Searching around I found this explanation by chi on a different [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28624408/equal-vs-left-arrow-symbols-in-haskell):
"x <- action runs the IO action, gets its result, and binds it to x"

Is the "<-" in the question linked above different to the "<-" used in the code I copied above? Does xs run inside xs? I'd be grateful if someone could explain to me what's going on here.

Comment: List comprehension syntax is basically just `do` expresssion syntax, which is syntactical sugar for some expressions with binds.

Comment: The `xs` on the LHS is the argument of the function, and on the RHS it is the actual function definition. It's no different than `f x = x + 3`. In this case, the `<-` operator just means to take successive values from the `xs` list and call them each `x` as you go through the loop.

Comment: `<-` isn't really an operator; it's just part of the syntax of a list comprehension.

Comment: yes, the "<-" in the question linked above (part of monadic [tag:do-notation] syntax) *is* different to the "<-" used in the code (part of list comprehension syntax). No, xs does not "run inside xs", it is meaningless to say this. `xs` on the right of `=` (a variable) refers to the `xs` on the left (i.e. `boomBangs`'s parameter).

Comment: Thanks everyone! Learned a bunch of new things, appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list comprehension is in essence just syntactical sugar for:

```
import Control.Monad(guard)

boomBangs :: Integral i => [i] -> [String]
boomBangs xs = do
    x <- xs
    guard (odd x)
    return (if x < 10 then "BOOM!" else "BANG!")
```

This is thus a [`do` expression [Haskell report]](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-470003.14), and as the report says, it is syntactical sugar. It is syntactical sugar for:

```
boomBangs xs = xs >>= \x -> (guard (odd x) >> return (if x < 10 then "BOOM!" else "BANG!"))
```

For a list the `Monad` instance is defined as:

```
instance Monad [] where
    (>>=) = flip concatMap
    return x = [x]
```

Furthermore the `guard` is defined as:

```
guard :: Monad m => Bool -> m ()
guard True = pure ()
guard False = empty
```

and the default implementation of `(>>)` is:

```
(>>) :: Monad m => m a -> m b -> m b
(>>) u v = u >>= \_ -> v
```

So the `boomBangs` is basically implemented as:

```
boomBangs xs = concatMap (\x -> (guard (odd x) >>= \_ -> [if x < 10 then "BOOM!" else "BANG!"])) xs
             = concatMap (\x -> concatMap (\_ -> [if x < 10 then "BOOM!" else "BANG!"]) guard (odd x)) xs
```

Since for a list, the `guard` can be specialized to:

```
-- guard for the Monad []
guard :: Bool -> [()]
guard True = [()]
guard False = []
```

It thus means that if the `guard` gets a `True`, it returns a singleton list, and for `False` an empty list. This thus means that given the guard holds, the `concatMap (\_ -> [if x < 10 then "BOOM!" else "BANG!"])` will return the content in the `[if x < 10 then "BOOM!" else "BANG!"]`, if the guard fails, it will return an empty list. The guard acts thus as some sort of filter.

So now what is the `x <-`. If we look at how the `do`-expressions are desugared, an `x <- foo`, corresponds to the `foo >>= \x -> ...`.

For list comprehensions, `x <- ...` acts as some sort of "enumerator": it will enumerate over all elements in the list, and `x` will each time obtain one of the elements in the list to do further processing.