# Data.Vector.Mutable field can not be written/set properly? : Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have struggled for days to compose a `data` structure that has a field of mutable value of `Data.Vector.Mutable`

I confirmed `Data.Vector.Mutable` itself behaves as I expected; however once it's included into a structure, somehow stops working against my expectation.

Below is a demo-code that simply has `newVal`, `getVal` and `setVal` targeting the mutable field value of the structure.

`newIO` is the constructor of the data structure typed as `newIO :: a -> A a`.

```
module Main where
import Control.Monad.Primitive (PrimMonad (PrimState))
import qualified Data.Vector.Mutable as M 
------------------------------------ 
data A a = A
  { ioVal :: IO (M.MVector (PrimState IO) a)
  }

newIO :: a -> A a
newIO = \a -> A (newVal a)
------------------------------
newVal :: a -> IO (M.MVector (PrimState IO) a)
newVal = \a -> do
  val <- M.new 1
  M.write val 0 a
  return val

getVal :: A a -> IO a
getVal = \aA -> do
  val <- ioVal aA
  M.read val 0

setVal :: a -> A a -> IO ()
setVal = \a -> \aA -> do
  val <- ioVal aA
  M.write val 0 a
------------------------------
main :: IO ()
main = do
  let ioA = newIO (5 :: Int)
  (getVal ioA) >>= print -- 5
  setVal 10 ioA
  (getVal ioA) >>= print -- 5 ?? expected 10
```

So, here, to confirm the basic behavior of **set/get** of the structure, I try to create, read, (re)write, and (re)read the mutable value of the field; however, it does not work as expected as the **set** should perform.

What's wrong with the code? Please advise.

Comment: Reading about [`let` vs `<-`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28624408/equal-vs-left-arrow-symbols-in-haskell) could help.

Comment: @chi Thank you. I thought I understand the de-sugar of `do`, but obviously not entough to make the mistake as you kindly thoroughly explained.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A main property of Haskell is referential transparency: we can always replace defined entities with their definitions. Now consider the posted code:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  let ioA = newIO (5 :: Int)
  (getVal ioA) >>= print -- 5
  setVal 10 ioA
  (getVal ioA) >>= print -- 5 ?? expected 10
```

This defines `ioA`, so we can replace it with its own definition. We get:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  (getVal (newIO (5 :: Int))) >>= print -- 5
  setVal 10 (newIO (5 :: Int))
  (getVal (newIO (5 :: Int))) >>= print -- 5 ?? expected 10
```

Now we can see the problem: we create three independent vectors. The issue is that `let ioA = ...` defines an IO action (roughly, an imperative procedure) that we can call multiple times later on.
But we don't want that: we want `newIO (5 :: Int)` to be executed only once.

For that, we must avoid `let` and use monadic bind (`<-`, in `do` blocks).

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  ioA <- newIO (5 :: Int)   -- run the action, just once
  (getVal ioA) >>= print
  setVal 10 ioA
  (getVal ioA) >>= print
```

This will trigger a bunch of type errors, since e.g. `getVal` is no longer passed an IO action, but is passed the *result* of the IO action. This is what we want, though, so we need to fix the types accordingly.

Start by removing `IO` here:

```
data A a = A
  { ioVal :: M.MVector (PrimState IO) a
  }
```

Indeed, we don't want to store a procedure that makes a vector, we want to store the vector.

Consequently, we need to *remove* `<-` in favor of `let` in a few other points.

```
getVal :: A a -> IO a
getVal = \aA -> do
  let val = ioVal aA  -- no IO action to run here
  M.read val 0
```

Also, `newIO` must return an `IO` value.

```
newIO :: a -> IO (A a)
newIO = \a -> fmap A (newVal a)
```

I think you can figure out the rest now.

Comment: Thanks for your elaborated answer!! I understand now. In fact, I tried this pattern and worked before I ask this Questtion, and thre reason I wanted to make it `newIO :: a -> A a` is..  When I implement a functor/monad on this, with `newIO :: a -> IO (A a)` I have to write   `ioA  |> fmap f  >>= fmap f` then I wanted to avoid the mix of the pipeline-operator and monad-operator.

Comment: Now, I understand it seems I have to give up having a type of `newIO :: a -> A a` as the foundation. Your explanation does make sense. Thanks again.

Comment: I really appreciate it. This answer leads me a proper deeper understanding do/IO-monad handling.

Comment: I made new Quesion. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71082667/what-would-be-the-concise-simplest-identity-monad-with-mutable-io-in-haskell