# Open file in haskell, passing filepath in C FFI call (CString)

Tags: c, haskell, ffi, haskell-ffi

I want to open a file in Haskell, but I want the top level function to be called from C (I want to pass the filepath from C).

I'm having trouble getting the `filepath` `CString` into a type that I can use `readFile` on.

Here's my first attempt, adapting the [example](https://wiki.haskell.org/Calling_Haskell_from_C) from the docs:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}

import Foreign.C.Types
import Foreign.C (CString, peekCString)

openFileDoStuff :: String -> IO Bool
openFileDoStuff filename = do
    lines <- (fmap lines . readFile) filename

    print lines
    -- do stuff with lines

    return True

openFilepathHs :: CString -> IO Bool
openFilepathHs cstr = openFileDoStuff (peekCString cstr)

foreign export ccall openFilepathHs :: CString -> IO Bool
```

I get a compiler error passing `(peekCString cstr)` to `openFileDoStuff`:

```
• Couldn't match type: IO String
                 with: [Char]
```

If I change the signature of my function to `openFileDoStuff :: IO String -> IO Bool`, I then can't use the `filename` parameter in the `readFile` call:

```
• Couldn't match type: IO String
                 with: [Char]
```

If it's not abundantly clear, I am a newbie in Haskell. I know there's no way to convert `IO String -> String`, but there must be a way to actually use the `CString` type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `>>=` to combine IO actions.

```
openFilepathHs cstr = peekCString cstr >>= openFileDoStuff
```

Actually, this pattern of passing a piece of data through successive IO transformations is so common it has a standard combinator for abbreviation.

```
openFilepathHs = peekCString >=> openFileDoStuff
```

You can also use `do` syntax to hide calls to `>>=`, but as a beginner I personally found `do` syntax very difficult to understand before I understood how to make calls to `>>=` myself.

```
openFilepathHs cstr = do
    cstrContents <- peekCString cstr
    openFileDoStuff cstrContents
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to **[run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28624408/equal-vs-left-arrow-symbols-in-haskell)** the `IO String` and bind it to a variable:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}

import Foreign.C.Types
import Foreign.C (CString, peekCString)

openFileDoStuff :: IO String -> IO Bool
openFileDoStuff filename = do
    filenameString <- filename
    lines          <- (fmap lines . readFile) filenameString

    print lines
    -- do stuff with lines

    return True

openFilepathHs :: CString -> IO Bool
openFilepathHs cstr = openFileDoStuff (peekCString cstr)

foreign export ccall openFilepathHs :: CString -> IO Bool
```

Comment: It is very unusual to accept `IO` actions as arguments. There are a few reasons to do it, such as exception handling, launching threads, and a few others, but the vast majority of the time accepting a pure argument (and expecting the caller to "run" any actions it needs to build that pure value) is the way to go.